# Is Tkinter winfo_reqwidth "always up to date"?

Tags: python, tkinter

From the documentation:

```
w.winfo_width()

Returns the current width of w in pixels. See the remarks on geometry
updating under .winfo_geometry(), above. You may prefer to use the
.winfo_reqwidth() method, described above; it is always up to date.
```

Not according to my experience. The following program prints the **same value** twice after each click on the label. The value changes line to line.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
t = "a label"
padx = 0
f = Frame(root, padx=padx, bg='red')
l = Label(f, text=t, bg='yellow')
def cb(e):
    global t, padx
    w = f.winfo_reqwidth()
    print w,
    t = t + 'x'
    padx += 10
    f.configure(padx=padx)
    l.configure(text=t)
    #f.update_idletasks()
    w = f.winfo_reqwidth()
    print w
f.place(x=0,y=0)
l.pack()
l.bind('<Button-1>', cb)
mainloop()
```

Prints:

```
49 49
76 76
103 103
```

Uncomment the f.update_idletasks line and it prints:

```
49 76
76 103
103 130
```

Is the documentation wrong? Am I reading it wrong? Is there any way to retrieve the required width and height of a widget immediately after changing it?

Comment: There is a difference between _width_ and _reqwidth_. You mention one in the title and the other in the body of your question. Which are you asking about?

Comment: No, both in the title and the code I refer to reqwidth. I just quote the width documentation because it says that reqwidth is always up to date. I only care about reqwidth.

Comment: Which documentation is this from? The [Tcl/Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M29) has a different text.

Comment: Tkinter: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html

Comment: The window doesn chage size inmediately after you call `configure`, some events need to be processed first.